# i have already assigned lastnode=self.head in if statement . SO why is this error saying that reference before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

[image]

I have already assigned `lastnode=self.head` in `if` statement. So why is this error saying that reference before assignment?

Comment: Hello, @Mohammad! Could you, please, attach the code using code snippets, not screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lastnode` is a local variable, that's why the first line of `else` statement can't be executed (at that moment `lastnode` has no attributes like `next`).

If you execute the code block after the `if` statement, the code block after `else` wont be executed and vice versa, if the condition is wrong, `if` part won't be executed. Read mode about [if statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_if_else.htm)